# unable to Spring Security working in existing application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am on day 3 of trying to get this to work and haven't had much luck.
Here's the use scenario (just summarizing using my own words here):

> Within the existing application we need to integrate Spring security.  User login configuration cannot change and we want to use standard annotations within spring (*@Secured* and *@PreAuthorize*) to be able to lock down access to RESTful endpoints.  Internal objects can be wrapped but are not permitted to be altered.

I added all of the core dependencies in Maven for security:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I took the custom *User* class that was in the system and created two wrappers for it to plug into the Spring Security Framework:

1. *CustomAuthentication* implementing *org.springframework.security.core.Authentication*
2. *CustomUserDetails* implementing *org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails*

I then created a *org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService* implementation that is annotated using *@Service("userDetailService")*.  That completed the basic Java-side implementation for the Spring Security that I thought I needed in order to get things running.

I created a class *com.myapp.rest.SecurityTestController* that looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/security-test")
public class SecurityTestController {

  @RequestMapping("wide-open/{name}")
  @ResponseBody
  public String restWideOpen(@PathVariable String name, HttpSession session) {
    return "Hello, " + name + ", from a wide-open RESTful service.";
  }

  @Secured("ROLE_XYZ")
  @RequestMapping("require-auth/{name}")
  @ResponseBody
  public String restRequireAuthorization(@PathVariable String name, HttpSession session) {
    return "Hello, " + name + ", from a RESTful service requiring authorization.";
  }
}
```

I also updated the internal logging code to add (which was implemented as a *@Conroller* by the original developer):

```
Authentication customAuthentication = new CustomAuthentication(user);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(customAuthentication);
```

On logout I just simply added:

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

That all seems fine, compiles with not issues, etc.  So I decided to move on to the configuration side of things in order to get the application working with security.  Without any changes I was able to access both interfaces using the basic URL (in this case that happens to be *localhost:8080/myapp/security-test/...*).

So here's the configs:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

  <display-name>MyApp</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myapp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/myapp/**</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/servlet.properties" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="${maxProfileImageSize}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${datasource.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.myapp.bean" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/velocity/"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/velocity.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/servlet.properties"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**applicationContext-security.xml**

```
<beans ...>
  <sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

  <sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/myapp/login" access="permitAll" />
  </sec:http>

  <sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailService" />
  </sec:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

And finally:  **myapp-web-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/servlet.properties" />

  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
  <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="sessionInterceptor" class="com.myapp.web.interceptor.SessionInterceptor" />
  </mvc:interceptors>

  <bean id="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <util:list>
        <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />
      </util:list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

  <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
      <property name="useTrailingSlashMatch" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Now comes the problem:

Everything reminds exactly the same.  I can access the RESTful services without having the roles be validated.  When I start Tomcat in debug my *UserDetailsService* implementation never actually gets invoked.

What am I missing?  This is completely frustrating me as I've never had problems with Spring Security like this before.

**UPDATE**

I figured it out.
Of all things to miss, I needed to add this to `myapp-web-servlet.xml`:

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

Now I just need to figure out how to get it to appropriately load my roles between session restarts.

Comment: Can't answer my own question yet so I just posted it in the root description under "UPDATE".

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your mappings:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Tried that with no success.  If I add `<sec:intercept-url pattern="/visualizer/**" access="ROLE_XYZ" />` I get "cannot evaluate expression.  It seems like it's just not recognizing the annotations *at all*.

Comment: but in your console output do you see if spring security checks for the access? if not maybe context file is not loading properly, try to separate them without using *